# How to Sort a 2Dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I need to sort a 2 dimensional array in increasing order.

Example:

Before:

```
5.1            3.3

6.3            4.8

4.9            6.9

7.4            5.2

3.6            7.4
```

After:

```
3.6            3.3

4.9            4.8

5.1            5.2   

6.3            6.9   

7.4            7.4
```

Comment: Is there anything that you've already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try like this using  [Arrays#Sort(T[] a, Comparator c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29):

```
java.util.Arrays.sort(array, new java.util.Comparator<double[]>() {
    public int compare(double[] a, double[] b) {
        return Double.compare(a[0], b[0]);
    }
```

Comment: Won't that keep both rows of numbers together?  From the sample input it looks like each column sorts independently.

Comment: I got it.It sorted each column.

Answer (score 2):

```
I think first you convert your 2D array into 1D than sorted your array after that
again convert it into 1D to 2D and another way is to sort you array

 List<Double> ar = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<array[i].length;j++){
            ar.add(a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(ar);
    for (Double double1 : ar) {
        System.out.println(double1);
    }
}
```

Output is 3.3
3.6
4.8
4.9
5.1
5.2
6.3
6.9
7.4
7.4

Answer (score 1):

[Previous answer](http://pastie.org/8785816)

```
double[][] array = {
                    {5.1, 3.3}, 
                    {6.3, 4.8}, 
                    {4.9, 6.9}, 
                    {7.4, 5.2}, 
                    {3.6, 7.4}, 
                   };
// for the number of columns in each row (2D so 0 and 1)
for (int col = 0; col <= 1; col++) {

    // create a temporary array to store this column in the 2D array
    double[] thisColumn = new double[array.length];

    // asign the temporary column values
    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
        thisColumn[row] = array[row][col];
    }

    // sort that column
    Arrays.sort(thisColumn);

    // reassign it back to the original array
    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
         array[row][col] = thisColumn[row];
    }
}
// print it out
for (double[] r : array) {
    for (double c : r) {
        System.out.print(c + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

---

Output:

```
3.6    3.3  
4.9    4.8  
5.1    5.2  
6.3    6.9  
7.4    7.4
```